# Rotate a rectangle at origin

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

d3, javascript, css beginner here

I am trying to rotate a rectangle without changing origin. I used css  transform: rotate(20deg);
But it changes the original x and y positions. I tried using  transform-origin: 0 0;

But doesn't work. Please find the code below

https://codepen.io/zubair57/pen/NWjXNQJ

```
.rotate {
  fill:pink;
   transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a snippet in your question (using the toolbar), which reproduces the issue when it is run.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you should add

```
transform-origin: 240px 225px;
```

This is because y+w/2 and x+h/2